# Update an individual sprite in a game loop

Tags: python, class, oop, livewires

I am trying to move only one sprite in a game loop including two sprites. I have included `spr1` in the `Bit.update()` method so if <kbd>w</kbd> is pressed `spr1.y -= 60`. In other words the sprite is assigned to `self` in the hope that only `spr1` will be moved when <kbd>w</kbd> is pressed.  However, in the current code, pressing <kbd>w</kbd> moves both `spr1` and `spr2`.  How can I refer to and update only `spr1` in the update method?

```
class Bit(games.Sprite):
    def update(self):
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_w):
            self = spr1
            self.y -= 60

def main():
    spr1_image = games.load_image("spr1.png")
    spr1 = Bit(image = spr1_image,
                x = games.screen.width / 10,
                y = games.screen.height / 10)

    spr2_image = games.load_image("spr2.png")
    spr2 = Bit(image = spr2_image,
                x = games.screen.width * 9 / 10,
                y = games.screen.height * 9 / 10)

    games.screen.add(spr1)
    games.screen.add(spr2)

    games.screen.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Each instance only refers to itself anyway; calling `self.y` only acts on the instance that `update` is called on.

Comment: When I press w it moves both sprites. I'm trying to write the program so that pressing w moves spr1 alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**
The two sprites have different behavior, so you need different classes for them.

1. In `Bit`, take out the `self=spr1` line and you should be OK.  In `update()`, `self` is whatever the current sprite is - `spr1` or `spr2`.
2. In `main`, change `spr2` to

   ```
   spr2 = games.Sprite(image = spr2_image,    # <---- changed class
           x = games.screen.width * 9 / 10,
           y = games.screen.height * 9 / 10)
   ```

   Since `spr2` doesn't need to respond to the keyboard, it doesn't need any behaviour that `games.Sprite` doesn't already provide.  Therefore, you don't need to use `Bit` for it.

(Caveat: I haven't used livewires, so I may be missing something obvious :) )

Comment: I understand what you have done. My code has been simplified for clarity. There are tens of sprites in the actual program and I'm hoping to avoid writing a class for each one. I want some way (like self=spr1) to move single sprites.

Comment: Whether there's a better way depends on how you have structured your code.  Rather than totally changing this question, would you please add a separate question, linking to this one, with more details about your many-sprite use case?  Please include how you decide which sprite you want to move.  For example, do you have some notion of a single sprite being the "active sprite" at any given time?  Thanks!